# How to add a delimiter/separator to a Rails block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, block, delimiter

I have the following block:

```
<% @place.each do |f| %>
  <%= f.name %><br>
  <%= f.type %>
<% end %>
```

which prints horizontally using `display: inline-block`. How can I add a seperator or delimiter in between each pair, but not after the last one?

It should look something like this:

```
printout - printout - printout - printout
```

Comment: Why do you use block, but keep using instance variables instead of block variable?

Comment: in your code you have create `f` object of `@place` and while printing you used `@place.name`

Comment: @Avdept Oh wow, stupid mistake. I wrote this question in a hurry. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach, without a counter:

```
<% @place.each do |f| %>
  <%= f.name %><br>
  <%= f.type %>
  <% if f != @place.last %>
    <div class="delimiter">-</div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `join` method of Arrays :

```rb
<%=
  @place.map { |f| "#{f.name}<br>#{f.type}" }
        .join(' - ')
        .html_safe
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone wrote an excellent answer that worked, but he took it down before I could accept it as the right one. Basically, I added an index to the block:

```
<% @count = @place.count %>
<% @place.each_with_index do |f, index| %>
  <%= f.name %><br>
  <%= f.type %>
  <% if index + 1 < @count %>
    <div class="delimiter">-</div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and then styled the delimiter with `display: inline;`.

Thank you, whoever posted that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some remake of barbolo version, that caches last:

```
<% @place.each_with_object(@place.last) do |f, last| %>
  <%= f.name %><br>
  <%= f.type %>
  <%= "-" unless f == last %>
<% end %>
```